# NPoco/Petapoco: Dataset too large for Fetch<T>

Tags: c#, petapoco, npoco

I have some code which has to process through each record in a dataset, which I've retrieved from the database via

```
List<Poco> lp = Fetch<Poco>("Select * from X");
```

My program crashes here with an out-of-memory exception.  If I'd do it the old-fashioned way, it would be like this: Create a reader then iterate through each retrieved record.  What is the best way to achieve something like this with Npoco / Petapoco?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need lazy-loading (where each result is loaded into memory as you iterate the enumerable), rather than eager-loading (where all results are loaded into memory at once).

[NPoco seems to use Fetch for eager-loading and Query for lazy-loading.](https://github.com/schotime/NPoco/wiki/Query-List)

Try using the Query method.

Comment: Wouldn't it get added into the List object as I iterate?  Do I need to delete the object to prevent that?

Comment: Query will return an enumerable. The results should be returned one-by-one as you iterate the enumerable, much like how your old-fashioned reader would iterate through each retrieved record. If you don't reference the objects elsewhere, they should be GC'd as usual.